# static var and functions: memory allocation in php

Tags: php, memory, static, allocation

I have a doubt in memory allocation with a php 5.3 script.
Imagine you have 2 static classes (MyData and Test) like these:

```
class MyData {
    private static $data = null;

    public static function getData() {
        if(self::$data == null)
            self::$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,);
        return self::$data;
    }
}

class Test {
    private static $test_data = null;

    public static function getTestData1() {
        if(self::$test_data==null) {
            self::$test_data = MyData::getData();
            self::$test_data[] = 6;
        }
        return self::$test_data;
    }

    public static function getTestData2() {
        $test = MyData::getData();
        $test[] = 6;
        return $test;
    }
}
```

And a simple test.php script:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 200000; $i++) {
    echo "Pre-data1 Test:\n\t" . memory_get_usage(true) . "\n";
    Test::getTestData1();
    echo "Post-data1 Test:\n\t" . memory_get_usage(true) . "\n";
}

for($i = 0; $i < 200000; $i++) {
    echo "Pre-data2 Test:\n\t" . memory_get_usage(true) . "\n";
    Test::getTestData2();
    echo "Post-data2 Test:\n\t" . memory_get_usage(true) . "\n";
}
```

I might suppose that the call to Test::getTestData1() will alloc memory for 2 static variables, while Test::getTestData2() will destroy $test (the copy of the static variable) on function return, so the second call is less "memory expensive".

But if I run the test.php script, memory_get_usage will show the same values for Test::getTestData1() and Test::getTestData2()

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing memory usage in the wrong way.
use `memory_get_usage(false);` to get the memory that is actually used by the script.
`memory_get_usage(true);` simply returns the memory allocated by System and this will always be the same for small scripts.

Comment: while you are at testing memory usage another usefull function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php

Comment: Thanks Pinoniq! I can now demonstrate that Test::getTestData2() is the  least expensive in terms of memory

Comment: I wouldn't say expensive. Eventually bad programming will be the tru bottleneck in your application. So I wouldn't focus that much on this kind of optimisation